# How can i echo a variable inside of this?

Tags: php

Hello how can I add an echo $name inside of this line ?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[latestbyauthor author="HERE" show="3"]'); ?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $name; echo do_shortcode(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your referring to concatenation, and you usually join a variable to a string with single dots (`.`).

usually like

```
"string 1" . $variable . "string 2";
```

your code would look like:

```
echo do_shortcode('[latestbyauthor author="' . $name . '" show="3"]');
```

Comment: What would this look like with two variables ie: author="' .$firstname. .$lastname.'"? I'm trying to figure out how to get address, city, province, postal code in one shortcode attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you meant? 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

if so, you can add $name with "." like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[latestbyauthor author="HERE" show="3"]').$name; ?>
```

But I guess you meant something else.

Comment: I meant I want to replace the HERE with the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just two other solutions

```
echo do_shortcode("[latestbyauthor author=\"$name\" show=\"3\"]");
echo do_shortcode(sprintf('[latestbyauthor author="%s" show="3"]', $name));
```

[sprintf()](http://php.net/sprintf) is a nice function anyway :)